# How to fix empty insert in Database from reactjs frontend using php rest api?

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, rest, api

Update! I manage to fix the problem with my input in the database, but now I have another problem. When I insert 1 element in my database, my submit methods create 2 rows, 1 empty and 1 with my values.

Post.php

```
 public function addComment(){
    // Create query
    $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->table2 . ' SET content = :content, 
rating = :rating, doctor = :doctor';

    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // Clean data
    $this->content = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->content));
    $this->rating = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->rating));
    $this->doctor = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->doctor));

    // Bind data
    $stmt->bindParam(':content', $this->content);
    $stmt->bindParam(':rating', $this->rating);
    $stmt->bindParam(':doctor', $this->doctor);

    // Execute query
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    }

    // Print error if something goes wrong
    printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);

    return false;

}
```

Here I have the addComment function. All the variables are private $table2 = 'com';  public $content; public $rating;  public $doctor;

add_comment.php

```
   // Instantiate DB & connect
   $database = new Database();
   $db = $database->connect();

   // Instantiate blog post object
   $post = new Post($db);

   // Get raw posted data
   $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

   $post->content = $data->content;
   $post->rating = $data->rating;
   $post->doctor = $data->doctor;

   // Create post
   if($post->addComment()) {
    echo json_encode(
        array('message' => 'Post Created')
    );
   } else {
    echo json_encode(
        array('message' => 'Post Not Created')
    );
   }
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {

        content: '',
        rating: '',
        doctor: '',

  error:null
    }
  }

  handleFormSubmit = e => {
e.preventDefault();
    axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost/fak/api/post/add_comment.php',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  data: this.state,
})
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data)

    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error: error.message }));
  };

  render() {
return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Add comment:</p>
      <div>
          <form action="#" >
          <label>Message</label>
          <textarea id="content" name="content" placeholder="Write something.."
                    onChange={e => this.setState({ content: e.target.value     })}
                    value={this.state.message}
          ></textarea>

          <input type="text" id="rating" name="rating" placeholder="Rating"
                 value={this.state.rating}
                 onChange={e => this.setState({ rating: e.target.value })}
          />

              <label>Rating</label>
          <label>Doctor name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="doctor" name="doctor" placeholder="Doctor name"
                 value={this.state.doctor}
                 onChange={e => this.setState({ doctor: e.target.value })}
          />


          <input type="submit" onClick={e => this.handleFormSubmit(e)} value="Submit" />
        </form >
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

 export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The data keys that you set in the frontend are completely different from what you expect at the backend.

You need something like:

```
this.state = {
  content: '',
  rating: '',
  doctor: '',
  error:null
}

// You need to adapt it everywhere you use `this.state`
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I fixed the problem, but now when I insert something the front creates 2 rows, 1 empty 1 with my values. How can I fix this?